# How to set the background color of Vuetify v-data-table row on hover?

Tags: css, sass, vuetify.js

How to set background color attribute of `<v-data-table>` ?

I tried this which works, but not with `scoped` attribute and it also affect group header rows:

```
<style lang="css">
.theme--light.v-data-table>.v-data-table__wrapper>table>tbody>tr:hover:not(.v-data-table__expanded__content):not(.v-data-table__empty-wrapper) {
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It could be that other CSS might be affecting the element. Please post the demo of your code using Codesandbox.

Comment: I just updated my post, it actually works, but not very nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `item` slot of `<v-data-table/>` and add your class to that custom table row element.

```html
<v-data-table ...>

  <template v-slot:item="{item}">
    <tr class="green-bg">
      <td>{{item.property1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.property2}}</td>
      <td>{{item.property3}}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>

</v-data-table>
```

```css
.green-bg {
  /* Set the display to `table-row` because Vuetify makes `flex` */
  display: table-row;
}

.green-bg:hover {
  /* `!important` is necessary here because Vuetify overrides this */
  background: green !important; 
}
```

[image]

Here is a sample demo at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-gareth-84qp1?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:89-387).